# Ionic Cordova CORS local image

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, cors

I have an application that can edit images using canvas. All images are local images, not downloaded from a web server.

The issue is when I want to use toDataURL() method from canvas - I get the CORS related issue "Tainted canvases may not be exported".

In order to solve I need to add crossOrigin="anonymous" to the loaded image.
But in this case Image is not loaded as it asks for "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" from cordova.

Is there a way to override cordova so it adds the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to all requests to local images?

Project is developed using Cordova, Ionic and Angular.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a solution that works.

If you load images using src attribute the browser will throw the error if "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is not sent.

Another solution is to load image as base64 using cordova-plugin-file and use the base64 string in the src attribute. I also set the crossOrigin="anonymous" but may work without this as well.

When this image is drawn into canvas, there is no CORS related error as image is not loaded from URL.